# handling loading for multiple useEffect that run different things

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm starting to use `Hook` and I have a problem to handling multiple `useEffect`

current Hooks code:

```
//1st useEffect should run only on DidMount
React.useEffect(()=>{
  //Calling API only on didMount
},[])

//2st useEffect should run on Context value Changes
React.useEffect(()=>{
  //Processing Context Foo and Context Bar on didMount and didUpdate
},[foo, bar])
```

My Expected Result is to add a loading while 2 `useEffect` is run on `didMount`

I can achieve it by using `class Component` like this

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading:true},()=>{
      //Call API
      
      //Processing Context Foo and Context Bar

      //on CallAPI and Processing Context is done
      this.setState({isLoading:false})

    })
  }
```

how can i achieve it using `Hooks`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your usecase. What are the 2 useEffects doing?

Comment: In the secound useState you can call api and achive showing loader and no need to use the first useEffect.
Note : just add proper condition for foo, bar values.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply done by defining multiple is-loading states with the `useState` hook. We can have
either

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState({ first: true, second: false });
```

or

```
const [isLoadingFirst, setIsLoadingFirst] = useState(true);
const [isLoadingSecond, setIsLoadingSecond] = useState(true);
```

After this, you can update the is-loading state which is related to the `useEffect`

More details on `useEffect` and `useState` can be found [React Hooks cheat sheet: Best practices with examples](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-hooks-cheat-sheet-unlock-solutions-to-common-problems-af4caf699e70/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
   setIsLoading(true);
    //Call API

    //on CallAPI and Processing Context is done
   setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

you can do same thing using hooks.